# is the possible for nested level preloading in GORM GOLANG?

Tags: mysql, go, kubernetes, go-gorm

Example

```
db.Preload("Orders.Orders.Orders").Preload(clause.Associations).Find(&users)
```

So can i put dynamically Nth level preloading in golang?

Actually what I want

If I write only Orders in preaload so I want to get n level preloading data

```
db.Preload("Orders").Preload(clause.Associations).Find(&users)
```

For an example we can take post has many comment and comment has many comments

```
db.Preload("comments.comments.comments").Preload(clause.Associations).Find(&users)
```

So instead of multiple time write `comments.comments.comments`
is the possible can I write with single `comment` ?

SO I WANT DYNAMICALLY NESTED PRELOADING IN GOLANG
THANK YOU IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 0):

Right now that is not possible. You could try to see if GORM has any settings to make this possible. I've seen a gorm tag like `gorm:"preload:true"`